# Need a break or finish in Promise chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm looking for a technique to drop to the last catch() on a promise chain (or a finish() or something like that - a terminal method of some sort) without having to maintain a "completed" state variable and a bogus finished() promise that I'm using now that requires the state variable to be checked after each catch and the finished() to be thrown (again). The process would be far easier to read and maintain in a chain with some sort of "drop to the last catch" method. At the moment I'm using straight ES6, but other libs will be gratefully considered.

In short how do I do this?:

```
begin() // some promise method
.then()
.then(/* found out I'm done here - break out or drop to last then() */)
.then()
.then()
.catch()
```

Comment: if your second `then` returning a Promise when you found out you are not done?

Comment: No. Not a useful one.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an exception from *then* fulfillment function

```js
var p = Promise.resolve();

p.then(() => console.log(1))
 .then(() => { console.log(2); throw 'Oh no!'; })
 .then(() => console.log(3))
 .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

or return a rejected promise

```js
var p = Promise.resolve();

p.then(() => console.log(1))
 .then(() => { console.log(2); return Promise.reject('Oh no!'); })
 .then(() => console.log(3))
 .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Yes. A "DONE" exception was considered, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something basic before using exceptions as a normal control flow mechanism.

Comment: you can continue the flow within your second `then(...)`, if you provide a promise object when you are not done.
Yes, that means nesting the rest of the `then()` calls which, in my book, is totally fine

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just be able to break out of the promise chain by returning a rejected promise.

```
begin()
  .then(() => {
    if (/*we're done*/) {
      return Promise.reject('some reason');
    }
  })
  .then() // won't be called
  .catch() // Catch 'some reason'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can break promise chain by the help of throw error

```
function myFunction() {
       // our custom promise or some function return promise object
       return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
          setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('dai')
          }, 2000)
       })
    }


myFunction().then(data=>{
    console.log('main')
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('one')
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('two')
    throw new Error('custom breaked')
}).then(data =>{
    console.log('three')
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log('---------error---------')
    console.log(err.message) // custom breaked
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
})
```